# ASMX Web service call its own instance located at different location

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

I have one service located at US servers say 
`http://myservice/ProfileManagerWS/ProfileMGRWS.asmx`

When any client make a call, I need to check request header property. If property say its a call for Canadian instance, then redirect call to `http://ca-myservice/ProfileManagerWS/ProfileMGRWS.asmx`

Previously service was only located at US servers and we have hosted service into Canadian servers just now.

We do not want to make any code changes at consumers of 
`http://myservice/ProfileManagerWS/ProfileMGRWS.asmx`

Should I write HTTPModule or soap extension for US instance?

Also, should I add proxy to US instance to call Canadian instance?

Comment: Added paragraph breaks. Formatted URL's as code.

Comment: Anyone please? Can you suggest a way to intercept and redirect request coming toward web service? I do not want to make any change at client end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load balancing based on proximity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325523/load-balancing-based-on-proximity)

Comment: I am thinking of adding service's proxy in same project but Canandian URL. I have to call proxy methods in each web method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, unless your client application has functionality that will accept a redirect response you won't be able to alter your web service get that functionality.

What you would probably want to do is to implement **Geographical Load Balancing** at your DNS server.  If a Canadian requests the IP address for `myservice`, give them an IP address that goes to your Candian server that is also configured to accept requests for the `myservice` domain.

Comment: is it not possible to handle programmatically at US service end? I must mention here that I have to segregate Canadian request based on a parameter called client code. If company code is say "xy"   then redirect call to Canada service from US service.

Comment: You specified that you didn't want any change at the consumers end. Without knowing the capabilities of what the consumers are using to consume the web service, then no.